# SQL - Getting only a particular date for each record

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table called **form** with the following fields

```
StudentID
form
date
```

Separately there is a **student** table containing their info, and StudentID is a foreign key from that table.

When a student moves form, a new entry is added for them in this table. That way we have a record of when they moved.

I'm trying to make a query that will get all the information from the **student** table (for every student), and join to it the form they are currently in (ie, the form with the most recent date from the **form** table above).

I can do it for individual students, but can't find a way to do it for the entire **student** table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select s.*,
       max(f.date) as MostRecentDate,
       substring_index(group_concat(form order by date desc), ',', 1) as MostRecentForm
from student s join
     form f
     on s.StudentID = f.StudentId
group by s.StudentId;
```

Comment: That works perfectly. I wasn't aware of the group_concat function before now - and that's a very innovative use of it. Thankyou!